# IOS MDM Pushnotication issue

Tags: ios, mdm

Hi my team is implementing IOS MDM. We have Enterprise license. We are able to send payloads and commands to the iOS device.We are receving result from IOS Device.But while send the push notification it  is not performing any thing. Even in IPCU log also no issues are showing.
We are using JavaPNS for sending push notification.Almost every thing we implemented in IOS MDM except push notification.
**But when i install IOS application and sending push notification using JavaPNS it is showing push notification.**

1) is it possible to send push notification for IOS MDM services ?.
2)Can we send push notifications without installing IOS application on the IOS device.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you generated a certificate from Apple and configured it on your MDM server? What kind of push notification are you sending? There is a distinction between MDM push notifications and regular app notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We are able to send payloads and commands to the iOS device.We are
>   receving result from IOS Device.

How do you send payloads and commands to iOS device? Are you sending them through MDM?

If so, the only way to let device get new commands, profiles from a server is to send "wake up" oush notification through APNS.

> But while send the push notification it is not performing any thing.

That's where I got confused. In the case, if it doesn't do anything, device will never contact back a server and it will never receive commands. However, you said that it does.

> But when i install IOS application and sending push notification using JavaPNS it is showing push >notification.

I believe this is your problem - confusion with terminology.

- MDM protocol doesn't require any iOS application to be installed. iOS operation system has mdm agent built in. As soon as you configured MDM (installed MDM payload) and a device received "wake up" push notification (through APNS) then MDM agent will contact your server and request new commands.
- On other hand, you can create some application (which has nothing to do with MDM) and send push notification to it.

The only common thing between this and MDM is push notification transport. However, the push notification message which is send for MDM purposes ("wake-up" message) and to applications ("badges", "sounds" , 'messages") are different.

Please, can you review your question and try to separate out what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Hi victor thanks for your reply.We are sending Commands and Payloads through MDM server.The device receives notification from APNS and device will contact to MDM  Server.This part is working well. My question through MDM protocal can we send Pushnotifications(alerts,sounds,badges) to the device using APNS.

Comment: MDM protocol doesn't include anything to send push notification (alerts, sounds, badges) to the device. However, you can send push notification (with alert and so on) to some application on the device. This is done through APNS. However, as I remember, you need to have another push notification certificate (different from MDM certificate).